# Spring Security doesn't "remember" login accross subdomains

Tags: spring, security, cookies, authentication, subdomain

Setup:
we have a webapp that uses Spring Security. The mobile part has a different subdomain (e.g. m.example.com).

We got the following situation:

- User logs in on example.com.
- User gets redirected to m.example.com and is not logged in anymore, but should be.

If all cookies are deleted the other way around works.

We assume that spring uses different cookies for the login on the subdomain. Given that: Is there any way to tell spring to use the same cookie in all subdomains?

Thanks in advance and best regards
Jan

Answer (score 1):

Just set this config in your web.xml:

```
   <session-config>
       <cookie-config>
           <domain>example.com</domain>
       </cookie-config> 
   </session-config>
```

Application server is responsible but not Spring Security for session cookie (JSESSIONID) creation.